# JAXP on Android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a jar-library processing xml. It runs perfectly when using it with a desktop application. 
But using it within an Android App, it throws the following exception:

> org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException:
>   http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage

I could find out that it's throwing the above exception in the setProperty method.

public static final String JAXP_SCHEMA_LANGUAGE = "http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage";
    public static final String W3C_XML_SCHEMA = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";

```
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser saxParser = spf.newSAXParser();
saxParser.setProperty(JAXP_SCHEMA_LANGUAGE, W3C_XML_SCHEMA);
```

When Debugging the desktop app, I figured out that 'spf' is of type **com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl**

and on Android type of **org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactoryImpl**

Is there any solution to use JAXP_SCHEMA_LANGUAGE on Android?